# Как сделать медленную прокрутку на странице?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу сделать тяжелую ( медленную ) прокрутку страницы, чтобы скорость прокрутки можно было регулировать.
Я тестил jQuery.scrollSpeed ( 1.0.1 ) и он не дал мне желаемого результат, может я не так что-то прописал.

```
$(function() {  

    jQuery.scrollSpeed(100, 800, 'easeOutCubic');
    
});
```

Мне нужно получить тяжелую прокрутку, чтобы пользователь не смог быстро прокрутить страницу , заранее спасибо )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("ul li a").click(function(e) {
  // Первое - отменить переход по ссылке
  e.preventDefault();
  // Получаем ссылку на id элемента
  const href = $(this).attr("href");
  // Останавливаем прошлую анимацию
  $("html, body").stop();
  // Далее прокручиваем либо <html> либо <body> 
  // (универсально - оба: и <html> и <body>)
  // методом $.animate(), 
  // первый параметр - вертикальное смещение элемента,
  // второй параметр - это время в мс (2 сек).
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(href).offset().top }, 2000);
});

// Останавливаем анимацию при ручном скролле
$('html, body').on('wheel',function(e){
  $('html, body').stop();
  document.documentElement.scrollTop-=e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY/20;
});
let touches = [];
$('body')
  .on('touchstart',function(e){
    const newTouches = [...e.originalEvent.changedTouches];
    for(let touch of newTouches) {
      touches.push(copyTouch(touch));
    }
    return false;
  })
  .on('touchmove',function(e){
    const curTouches=[...e.originalEvent.changedTouches];
    let touchOffset=0;
    for(let touch of curTouches) {
      const prevTouchIdx = 
       touches.findIndex(prevTouch => 
         prevTouch.identifier==touch.identifier);
      const prevPageY = touches[prevTouchIdx].pageY;
      Object.assign(touches[prevTouchIdx],
        copyTouch(touch));
      touchOffset += touch.pageY - prevPageY;
    }
    /*console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop,
       -touchOffset-(curScrollTop-scrollOffset))*/
    document.documentElement.scrollTop+=-touchOffset/2;
    return false;
  })
  .on('touchend',function(e){
    const endTouches= 
 [...e.originalEvent.changedTouches];
    for(let touch of endTouches){
      touches.splice(touches.findIndex(prevTouch=> 
        prevTouch.identifier==touch.identifier),1);
    }
    return false;
  })
  .on('touchcancel',function(e){
    const cancelTouches=[...e.originalEvent.changedTouches];
    for(let touch of cancelTouches){
      touches.splice(touches.findIndex(prevTouch => prevTouch.identifier == touch.identifier),1);
     }
    return false;
  });

function copyTouch({identifier,pageX,pageY}){
  return {identifier,pageX,pageY};
}
```

```css
html,body {
background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
  overflow:hidden;
}

.section{
  height: 150vh;
}

ul {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 3rem;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #888;
}

h2 {
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 3px #000, -1px 1px 3px #000, 1px -1px 3px #000, 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/> 
<ul>
<li><a href="#top">top</a></li>
<li><a href="#section_1">Section 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#section_2">Section 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#section_3">Section 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#section_4">Section 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="section">
<h2 id="top">Top</h2>
</div>
<div class="section">
<h2 id="section_1">Section 1</h2>
</div>
<div class="section">
<h2 id="section_2">Section 2</h2>
</div>
<div class="section">
<h2 id="section_3">Section 3</h2>
</div>
<div class="section">
<h2 id="section_4">Section 4</h2>
</div>
```

По "утяжелению" скролла, первое что пришло в голову - отменять скролл и устанавливать его вручную. Но события как scroll так и wheel невозможно отменить. Тогда пришлось вращать их вручную.

Comment: а можешь сделать пример с задержкой прокрутки wheel ?

Comment: @MaximLensky  без проблем

Comment: если сможешь покажи только без jQuery

Comment: @DiD Мне нужно прокрутку по скроллу медленную и на всей странице, а не по якорям

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1093725/308951 а то на JQuery я делал уже а на js не смог

Comment: @MaximLensky что-то похожее мне и надо, но есть проблема с тем что он после остановки едет сам , как это убрать ?
вот пример того, какой я хотел скролл https://www.fusemedia.eu

Comment: там тоже едет скролл после того как я убираю палец с колёсика

Comment: щас @DiD сделает - он сильнее меня знает js

Comment: Если он @DiD сможет, я просто буду в шоке )))
Да, он там едет, но останавливается, а в твоем примере он дальше едет, если это убрать, чтобы он дальше не ехал, то это будет самое то

Comment: @MaximLensky jQuery там играет второстепенную роль. Можно и без него конечно)

Comment: @kah3vich вот теперь готово

Comment: @DiD твой код у меня почему-то вообще не работает, я его тест на своём проекте и отдельно, и ничего (

Comment: @meine твой код работает, только после прокрутки возвращает немного обратно к блоку, можно это как-то пофиксить ?

Comment: могу. только не понял, как он возвращает? но я потестирую сейчас.

Comment: @DiD я нашел очень простой способ, как реализовать мою идею, завтра может закину её сюда.
Но спасибо, что помог))

Comment: @kah3vich попробуй поскролить с мобильного!

Answer (score 2):

```js
class SmoothScroll {
  constructor(node) {
    this.settings = {
      node: node || window,
      html: document.documentElement,
      target: 0,
      scroll: 0
    };
    
    this.rAF = false;
    
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
    this.onWheel = this.onWheel.bind(this);
    this.onScroll = this.onScroll.bind(this);
    
    this.settings.node.addEventListener('wheel', this.onWheel, false);
    this.settings.node.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll, false);
  }
  
  update() {
    this.settings.scroll += (this.settings.target - this.settings.scroll) * .1;
    
    if (Math.abs(this.settings.scroll.toFixed(5) - this.settings.target) <= .47131) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(this.rAF);
      
      this.rAF = false;
    }
    
    this.settings.node == window
      ? scrollTo(0, this.settings.scroll)
      : this.settings.node.scrollTop = this.settings.scroll;
    
    if (this.rAF)
      this.rAF = requestAnimationFrame(this.update);
  }
  
  onWheel(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    
    const scrollEnd = (this.settings.node == window)
                    ? this.settings.html.scrollHeight - this.settings.html.clientHeight
                    : this.settings.node.scrollHeight - this.settings.node.clientHeight;
    
    this.settings.target += (e.wheelDelta > 0) ? - 70 : 70;
    
    if (this.settings.target < 0)
       this.settings.target = 0;
    
    if (this.settings.target > scrollEnd)
      this.settings.target = scrollEnd;
    
    if (!this.rAF)
      this.rAF = requestAnimationFrame(this.update);
  }
  
  onScroll(e) {
    if (this.rAF) return;
    
    this.settings.target = (this.settings.node == window)
                         ? pageYOffset || this.settings.html.scrollTop
                         : this.settings.node.scrollTop;
    
    this.settings.scroll = this.settings.target;
  }
}

new SmoothScroll();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

section { height: 100vh; }
section:nth-child(1) { background-color: yellow; }
section:nth-child(2) { background-color: black; }
section:nth-child(3) { background-color: green; }
section:nth-child(4) { background-color: purple; }
```

```html
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
```