# Как реализовать плавную прокрутку на страницу на сайте?

Tags: javascript

Хочу реализовать прокрутку на страницу вниз на сайте. Как на этом сайте  https://adv.ru/#Clients.
Как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1093700/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5/1093725#1093725 второй пример работает на мобиле и на компе

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать плавную прокрутку сайта как в примере?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1093700/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5)

Answer (score -2):

Можно js библиотекой moveTo воспользоваться.

https://github.com/hsnaydd/moveTo

> A lightweight (only 1kb gzipped) scroll animation javascript library without any dependency.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Спасибо за конструктивную критику. Исправлюсь.